Not able to share files with external users
We have a use case to share files created by internal user to be available to the external users automatically. The external user is the owner of the record, but still cannot see the file uploaded by an internal user.
The trigger below stamps the NetworkId on the ContentVersion
trigger applyNetworkId on ContentVersion (before insert) {
    
    // Black Diamond Hub community
    String networkId = '0DBVi00000002EjOAI';
    
    // Share files generated using GoCloudz PDF Generator with external users
    for(ContentVersion cv : trigger.new) {
          cv.NetworkId = networkId;
    }
}

A ContentDocumentLink record is created to link the ContentDocumentId and the External User Id.
ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
cdl.ShareType='V';
cdl.Visibility='AllUsers';
cdl.LinkedEntityId='0059b000007S9ycAAC'; //External User Id
cdl.ContentDocumentId = '0699b0000028QlnAAE';
insert cdl;

And we are seeing the file is shared with the external user when we navigate to the record >> Files section but the external user does not see it in the Community. Wondering what the issue is?

N.B. Relevant doc.

@Mitesh Sura
    
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore)
    {
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : Trigger.new) {
            if(cdl.LinkedEntityId!=null){
                if (cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Your Object API Name'){
                    cdl.visibility = 'AllUsers';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Add Files related list in community page for that object where You want files to be visible
//when internal user uploads file in the related list of the object mentioned in contentDocumentLInk Trigger it will be automatically shared with external users.


worked like a charm. Thank you Jenifa for the suggestion.
